# how to adjust size of content according to screen resolution in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[when I change screen resolution the image size changes from full sreen but the navbar remains in full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iraWp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the image to width: 100% and it will scale with the browser.

Or,

> Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with
>   .img-fluid. max-width: 100%; and height: auto; are applied to the
>   image so that it scales with the parent element.
>   [https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/][1]

So simply give the img a class of img-fluid.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is use div and add the image as the background of the div, lets say you want to call the `div` class as `hero-banner`. The css class would be :

```
// css
.hero-banner{
background-image: url('/images/location/hero.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: none; 
min-height:450px;
}



// html
<nav>
    ....
</nav>
<div class="hero-banner"></div>
```